# Change onclick() function multiple times (play/pause image change)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

```
<audio>
    <source src="data/music/track1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Audio element.
</audio>
<button type="button" class="button_media button-mini" onclick="aud_play_pause()">
    <img id="play_pause" src="data/play_button.png" onclick "changePlayPauseButton()">
</button>
<audio>
    <source src="data/music/track2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Audio element.
</audio>
<button type="button" class="button_media button-mini" onclick="aud_play_pause()">
    <img id="play_pause_two" src="data/play_button.png" onclick "changePlayPauseButtonTwo()">
</button>
<audio>
    <source src="data/music/track3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Audio element.
</audio>
<button type="button" class="button_media button-mini" onclick="aud_play_pause()">
    <img id="play_pause_three" src="data/play_button.png" onclick "changePlayPauseButtonThree()">
</button>
<script>
    var play_pause = "pause_button.png";

    function changePlayPauseButton() {
        if (play_pause == "pause_button.png") {
            document.images["play_pause"].src = "data/pause_button.png";
            document.images["play_pause"].alt = "pause";
            play_pause = "play_button.png";
        } else {
            document.images["play_pause"].src = "data/play_button.png";
            document.images["play_pause"].alt = "play";
            play_pause = "pause_button.png";
        }
    }

    var play_pause_two = "pause_button.png";

    function changePlayPauseButtonTwo() {
        if (play_pause_two == "pause_button.png") {
            document.images["play_pause_two"].src = "data/pause_button.png";
            document.images["play_pause_two"].alt = "pause";
            play_pause_two = "play_button.png";
        } else {
            document.images["play_pause_two"].src = "data/play_button.png";
            document.images["play_pause_two"].alt = "play";
            play_pause_two = "pause_button.png";
        }
    }

    var play_pause_three = "pause_button.png";

    function changePlayPauseButtonThree() {
        if (play_pause_three == "pause_button.png") {
            document.images["play_pause_three"].src = "data/pause_button.png";
            document.images["play_pause_three"].alt = "pause";
            play_pause_three = "play_button.png";
        } else {
            document.images["play_pause_three"].src = "data/play_button.png";
            document.images["play_pause_three"].alt = "play";
            play_pause_three = "pause_button.png";
        }
    }
</script>
```

I created a kind of playlist which appears only the button
play / pause . I also customized the button , so that the image automatically change when clicked . The problem is that I have several buttons !
What I like to do, is to change not only the image of the button itself when clicked but also the other button when it is in play mode ( pause image ) to be returned to the play mode (play image )

Go easy on me  guys
I  just started to code one month ago!
thanks

Comment: Hey, I'm implementing an example for you, I'm fixing some issues you have. I'll send you soon

Comment: Thanks I appreciate any help you can give me on this subject.
By the way,  i lacked informed you: 
Since i have at least 24 tracks and in the future they can be increased. I needed something like this:

https://www.musicbed.com/playlists/pop/141

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure if is that what you need but take a look the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/j6nbcpL9/

js:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('button').on('click', function(){
           var option = $(this).attr('data-btn');
            console.log(option);
            if(option === 'changePlayPauseButtonThree'){
                changePlayPauseButtonThree();
                ...
            }
            if(option === 'changePlayPauseButtonTwo'){
                changePlayPauseButtonTwo();
                ...
            }
            if(option === 'changePlayPauseButton'){
                changePlayPauseButton();
                ...
            }
        });
    });
```

Also, let me know if is not what you need to implement it properly. The code is not the best but I hope it's help.

Comment: Thanks For the Help and for the effort.

This  line code you gave me is very simple and works perfectly. The problem is that I have not only  3 button play / pause but  instead i have 24 and in the future they can become a lot more. Sorry, I should have explained this part . 

I want something like this:

https://www.musicbed.com/playlists/pop/141

So, despite the quality of the code You gave me, it  doesn't   solve my problem entirely. But with your help, I'm already start  seeing the light at the end of the tunnel

Thanks again

Comment: well you can use the same function for all the buttons you only have to manage it properly. Also maybe it can helps you https://github.com/happyworm/jPlayer @SamuelFurtado